# reading an excel file into Python and turn to JSON

Tags: python, json

I want to read a timesheet in form of excel file into python and be able to show the results in json format.the problem is the file has many empty cells and it shows them as Null.How do i delete those from the json file so  it be easy to read.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import ExcelFile


data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\TimesheetTemplate.xlsx")
data = data.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('}NaN{', '} {')
print(data)
```

the output of the dataframe is below.

```
"{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":\"TIMESHEET\",\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Employee\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":\"Submitted By\",\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":\"Ed Dom\",\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Name\",\"Unnamed: 4\":\"Ed Dom \",\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":\"Emp #\",\"Unnamed: 8\":1246,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Position\",\"Unnamed: 4\":\"Solution Architect\",\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":\"SSN\",\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Department\",\"Unnamed: 4\":\"Aeyuia\",\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":\"Manager\",\"Unnamed: 8\":\"Edll Douku\",\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Pay Period\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":\"Approved By\",\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":\"Te Mar\",\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"From:  \",\"Unnamed: 4\":154077100,\"Unnamed: 5\":\"To:  \",\"Unnamed: 6\":154110000,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":\"Date:\",\"Unnamed: 13\":1543536000000,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Account \\nDescription\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"Account\\nCode\",\"Unnamed: 9\":\"M\",\"Unnamed: 10\":\"T\",\"Unnamed: 11\":\"W\",\"Unnamed: 12\":\"Th\",\"Unnamed: 13\":\"F\",\"Unnamed: 14\":\"Sa\",\"Unnamed: 15\":\"Su\",\"Unnamed: 16\":\"Total\\nHours\",\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"EA Work, Goe Meetings (ARDF, TEA, DR, MRF, MRC) & Doc Reviews\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":3,\"Unnamed: 10\":2.5,\"Unnamed: 11\":2.5,\"Unnamed: 12\":2.5,\"Unnamed: 13\":2,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":12.5,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":12.5},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Concept,  Solution - Meetings (I)\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":4500,\"Unnamed: 9\":4,\"Unnamed: 10\":4,\"Unnamed: 11\":4,\"Unnamed: 12\":4,\"Unnamed: 13\":2,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":18,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":18.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"384 Me & Mink order restructuring\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"C1\",\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":0.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"C13072 vManaged \",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"C72\",\"Unnamed: 9\":1.5,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":1,\"Unnamed: 13\":1,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":3.5,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":3.5},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"C9 Global Etet - MeN International\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"C\",\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":1,\"Unnamed: 11\":1,\"Unnamed: 12\":1,\"Unnamed: 13\":1,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":4,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":4.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"C137 S Number Allocation\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"C13037\",\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":1,\"Unnamed: 11\":1,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":2,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":2.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"C Redundancy\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"C9\",\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":2,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":2,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":2.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":\"Total Hours  \",\"Unnamed: 9\":8.5,\"Unnamed: 10\":8.5,\"Unnamed: 11\":8.5,\"Unnamed: 12\":8.5,\"Unnamed: 13\":8,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":42,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":42.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":\"Total Overtime Hours  \",\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":0.0},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":\"*Calculated on a per-week basis.\",\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Notes and Remarks\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":\"Office Use Only\",\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":null,\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":\"Account\\nCode\",\"Unnamed: 18\":\"Account\\nCode\",\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null},{\"Unnamed: 0\":null,\"Unnamed: 1\":null,\"Unnamed: 2\":null,\"Unnamed: 3\":null,\"Unnamed: 4\":null,\"Unnamed: 5\":null,\"Unnamed: 6\":null,\"Unnamed: 7\":null,\"Unnamed: 8\":null,\"Unnamed: 9\":null,\"Unnamed: 10\":null,\"Unnamed: 11\":null,\"Unnamed: 12\":null,\"Unnamed: 13\":null,\"Unnamed: 14\":null,\"Unnamed: 15\":null,\"Unnamed: 16\":null,\"Unnamed: 17\":\"<>\",\"Unnamed: 18\":null,\"Unnamed: 19\":null,\"Unnamed: 20\":null}"
```

​

Comment: can you share the input sample?

Comment: I'm not familiar with panda so there may be a way to do this more efficiently but
`{key: value for key, value in json.loads(data).items() if value is not None }` will remove all null values.

Comment: a sample template  https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4lKaG6vneAhWkxYUKHWFXBOAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffitsmallbusiness.com%2Ftimesheet-templates%2F&psig=AOvVaw06z8uQ3Z6cSjPzPTA6t_En&ust=1543588668226422